# Django Mezzanine - Don't Overwrite Local Files with collecttemplates

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm trying to copy over the mezzanine core files to my project using the following:

```
python manage.py collecttemplates
```

but every time that I run this is overwrites my local changes to files such as base.html. How can I run this but choose for it to only add missing files, not overwrite updated ones?

Comment: Actually my answer below was incorrect - you should get prompted for any files that will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

The command doesn't currently support this behaviour, but it's a great idea - I've just opened an issue for it here: https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/1319

Meanwhile, to state the obvious workaround:

- Copy your project's templates directory to an external temporary directory
- Run collecttemplates
- Copy the external temporary directory back to your project's templates directory

Comment: You can also run collecttemplates with the -t option to collect individual templates. I do this to only get the templates I haven't copied already.

Comment: I'm new to django, so this may seem obvious. How do I know which templates I have and have not collected?